# Changing div parameter in Google programmable search does not rerender the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, google-search-console, google-search-api

I have build a React app containing a google programable search (cse). Within the div element I have added a custom parameter data-as_oq that is population with a state variable:

`<div className='gcse-search' data-as_oq={this.state.myvariable}></div>`

That parmeter is used to add search parameters to the google search (i.e. site:mysite.com). This works as expected when the app is rendered the first time. However, if I change this.state.myvariable the div is not re-rendered. I tried from setting the state with setState over to this.forceUpdate() withouth access. Not sure if this is intended behavior or if I am missing anything. Would appreciate any help!